# How stop video Youtube after closing modal window?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, youtube, youtube-api, bootstrap-modal, youtube-javascript-api

How can I stop a Youtube Video, which is inside a `Modal` from `Bootstrap`, when the `Modal` is closing?

I have tried this with no success:

```
$('#videoModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        callPlayer('vidwrap', 'stopVideo');
        $iframe = $(this).find( "iframe" );
        $iframe.attr("src", $iframe.attr("src"));
});
```

Comment: Use Colorbox http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ is more easy

Answer (score 0):

ok, I had this same issue, here with me I had a id called youtube-video, inside which i was adding my Iframe tag from youtube.com
watch-video - is the button, that toggled my modal visibility.
.close is the button, on which I was closing my modal.

What we are doing, is just removing the src from the video, on close click.

```
  $(function(){
      var url = $('#youtube-video iframe').attr('src');
      $('#watch-video').click(function() {
          $('#youtube-video iframe').show();
          $('#youtube-video iframe').attr('src', url);
      });
      $('button.close').click(function() {
          $('#youtube-video').hide();
          $('#youtube-video iframe').attr('src', '');
      });      
    });
```